# Multiply each element in one row and append new column in same dataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Want to multiply each element of a row and then add new result column for every row of the dataFrame.

I am able to extract each row from dataFrame.

```
df_temp.values[0,:]
array([18, 10,  5, 11, -2], dtype=int64)
```

But am not able to proceed after that. Tried using the `mul()` as-

```py
df.temp
        a   b   c   d  e
    p  18  10   5  11 -2
    r  -4   6 -19   2  1
    s   3 -14   1  -2  8
print(df_temp.mul(df_temp.values[0,:], axis=1))
```

But this is giving result:

```
     a    b   c    d   e
p  324  100  25  121   4
r  -72   60 -95   22  -2
s   54 -140   5  -22 -16
```

Expected output:

```
   a   b   c  d   e  result
p 18  10   5  11 -2  -19800
r -4   6 -19   2  1     912
s  3 -14   1  -2  8     672
```

Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: can it be done using df.eval() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`df.assign()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) with [`df.prod()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.prod.html) on `axis=1`:

```
df=df.assign(result=df.prod(axis=1))
print(df)
```

---

```
    a   b   c   d  e  result
p  18  10   5  11 -2  -19800
r  -4   6 -19   2  1     912
s   3 -14   1  -2  8     672
```

Comment: Thanks didn't knew `prod`.

Comment: @Rex5 i am not aware of that, since this question didnot ask for specific ways to achieve this, i believe it will be better if you ask a fresh question. :) Thanks

Comment: ok please if you come across `eval()` way too, do post that too here .

Answer (score 0):

**Using pd.eval()**

```
temp_df = df.copy()
temp_df['m']=pd.eval("temp_df.a*temp_df.b*temp_df.c*temp_df.d*temp_df.e")
df_temp

   a  b c  d e  m

p 18 10 5 11 -2 -19800

r -4 6 -19 2 1  912

s 3 -14 1 -2 8  672
```